# Postmaster: DMARC PASS, DKIM PASS, SPF FAIL, on postmaster

Tags: gmail, bulk-email, spf, dmarc

We are setting up our domain to meet gmails new policy.
Our company domain passed DMARC and DKIM but failing SPF on postmaster.
The success rate of SPF is 0%.

The header of the received emails from the domain says SPF and DMARC are all successful.
*I checked with my gmail account

Does anyone have similar issue?

Comment: Can you share if the email domain used in Return-Path address and FROM address are the same or share the same organizational domain? This could be an alignment issue.

Comment: You must declare in your SPF record all the servers that are allowed to send (or forward) emails on your behalf. This includes the *from address* and the *return address* (usually are the same).

Comment: @LuisAlbertoBarandiaran can you elaborate? SPF works only on the Return-Path a.k.a. envelope from or  bounce address, as per RFC, as far as I can tell. The whole reason DMARC came about is because SPF (like DKIM) doesn't require the used domains to align with the FROM domain.

Comment: Both must align, the FROM and the RETURN-PATH. Here's an article that can explain it in more detail: https://mxtoolbox.com/dmarc/spf/spf-alignment

Answer (score 0):

I would check if the `return_path` shares the same domain the `from` address. `return_path = bounce.domain.com` and `from = domain.com` has proper alignment, but `return_path = domain_2.com` and `from = domain.com` does not.

If the SPF is still continuing to not align, then I would check the header and see if aspf = `s` or `r`. I recommend using `r` which allows a more relaxed DMARC policy, allowing SPF and DMARC alignment.